# COPY SOURCEDATA TO 2 DIFFERENT SHEETS WITH VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I'm trying to get the sourcedata from a range of cells on an "input sheet" for data entry to copy this information to 2 different sheets. After this copy, I will use one sheet to leave for all data, and manipulate the other sheet for tracking.

This is what I've gotten so far, but I get an error that an object is required.

```
Sub CopySource()
    Dim NextRow As Range
    With Sheets(Array("MasterData", "MainData")).Select
      Set NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
    End With
    Range("SourceData").Copy
    NextRow.PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False
    Application.CutCopyMode = False
    Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

Comment: The code works great with just one sheet: 
`With Sheets("MasterData").Select`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just do each copy individually, then:

```
Sub CopySource()
  Range("SourceData").Copy
  Sheets("MasterData").Cells(Sheets("MasterData").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial _
           Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False
  Sheets("MainData").Cells(Sheets("MainData").Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1).PasteSpecial _
           Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
End Sub
```

Possible fix for the original code:

```
Sub CopySource()
  Dim NextRow() As Range  'This makes an array of ranges
  With Sheets(Array("MasterData", "MainData")).Select
    'not sure if this will now populate multiple elements of NextRow() with multiple
    'ranges, one from each sheet, above
    Set NextRow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Offset(1)
  End With
  Range("SourceData").Copy
  NextRow(0).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False
  NextRow(1).PasteSpecial Paste:=xlPasteValuesAndNumberFormats, Transpose:=False
  Application.CutCopyMode = False
  Set NextRow = Nothing
End Sub
```

Not sure if that'll work, but it might be worth a try

Comment: I was trying to figure out how to adjust the code to copy individually until I found how to use an array. I guess I need more education before using an array. Thank you @FreeMan.

Comment: I am getting an error for an unqualified reference. It highlights the first `.Rows` entry.

Comment: Ah, because I took out the `With`. You can either wrap a `With` around each statement, or fully qualify the `.Rows`.

Comment: My guess is that the `Array()` piece didn't work because `NextRow` is a single element `Range`. See edits coming for a possible workaround to that...

Comment: The `.Rows` is still not allowing the macro to proceed. I've tried to make corrections with the original and the possible fix to get the errors to stop.

Comment: I've updated the "individually" code to fully qualify `.Rows`. I believe that will do it for you

Comment: The "individually" code worked perfectly @FreeMan. Thank you for the help two days in a row!